The sweet alert closed before the timer set up. It not working properly
I have a form. When this submit if have some data already return a message  and that works. But if the response data is success return another message and  this are closing before the timer with only fews seconds. I need that the message closed after 45 s .
const handleDuplicateIdentityNumber = async foundCandidate => {
            await Swal.fire({
                title: `Error`,
                html: `<span style="font-size:24px:"> Candidatu ho Númeru dokumentu identifikasaun:
                    <strong>${formData.Número_documento_Identificação}</strong> aplika tiha ona ho Kode applikasaun: <strong> ${foundCandidate.applicationCode}.</strong>
                    Candidato com Número Documento de Identificação: <strong>${formData.Número_documento_Identificação}</strong>
                    já realizou a aplicação com code de aplicação :  <strong> ${foundCandidate.applicationCode}.</strong>
                    Por favor hakerek númeru aplikasaun (Kode Aplikasaun Online) <strong> ${foundCandidate.applicationCode}</strong>`,
                confirmButtonText: 'Ok',
            });
            navigateToSearch('/');
        };

try {
            const response = await axios.post(
                `${baseURL}public/db/submitedDataII/`,
                formData,
                {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                }
            );
            setIsLoading(false);

            console.log('Backend response:', response.data);
            console.log(formData.applicationCode);

            if (response.data.success) {
                Swal.fire({
                    position: 'center',
                    title: 'Código da Aplicação:',
                    html: `<strong style="font-size: 36px;">${formData.applicationCode}</strong><br/>
                       <strong style="font-size: 20px;">Ita-Boot nia aplikasaun online nia númeru ${formData.applicationCode}</strong>.
                       Tenke hakerek númeru aplikasaun (Kode Aplikasaun Online) no rai didi’ak númeru ida-ne’e!
                       Prosesu aplikasaun ba Bolsa Kandidatu seidauk kompletu. Ita-Boot sei tenke ba Serviço Municipal
                       de Educação ka INFORDEPE iha Dili hodi kompleta prosesu no submete dokumentu sira.`,
                    confirmButtonText: 'Ok',

                    timer: 45000,
                    icon: 'success',
                }).then(() => {
                    navigateToSearch('/'); // Navigation after closing the alert
                });
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error during backend request:', error.message);
            alert(
                'Ocorreu um erro ao submeter a aplicação. Por favor, tente novamente.',
                'error'
            );
        } finally {
            setIsLoading(false);
        }

here are some dependencies in the app:
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-hook-form": "^7.49.3",
"react-router-dom": "^6.21.3",
"react-scripts": "5.0.1",
"sweetalert": "^2.1.2",
"sweetalert2": "^11.10.8",
